# DC motor fan speed control with Temperature Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor, transistor

I used this circuit schematic for the project however, when DC Motor starts to work, temperature value is increasing abnormally high. How can I solve this problem? It shows abnormal high values like 70, 85 ,101 etc.

[image: Schematic]

```
#define TEMPERATURE A0
#define fan 3
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
}



void loop(){
float temp = analogRead(TEMPERATURE);    //Read the analog pin
temp = temp * 0.48828125;   // convert output (mv) to readable celcius

Serial.print(temp);
//print the temperature status
Serial.print('\n');
delay(1000);  


 if (temp<=24){
  analogWrite(fan, 51);
 
  delay(1000);

}
else if (temp<=26 && temp>24){
  analogWrite(fan,122);
  
  delay(1000);
 
}
 else if (temp<=30 && temp>26){
  analogWrite(fan,223);

  delay(1000);

}
else if (temp>30){
  analogWrite(fan,255);
 
  delay(2000);
 
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Raul, please edit your original question instead of asking a new one. Duplicate: [DC Motor fan control with Temperature sensor](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79755/dc-motor-fan-control-with-temperature-sensor)

Comment: I think the problem lies in the fact, that you did not calibrate the sensor. You just take the analog reading and multiply it with `0.48828125`. Where did you get this value from? And what kind of sensor do you use. The schematic shows a sensor with 3 pins. Is it perhaps a digital sensor like the 18B20? You can not use the analog port to read a digitial sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that whatever temperature you are measuring is not rising when the motor is on.

I see that you are sharing the power/ground between your temperature sensor IC and the motor.  Motors are extremely noisy from an electrical viewpoint and it's almost certainly causing your temperature sensor to malfunction.

It would be best to separate the temp sensor power/ground connections from the motor power/ground connections completely.  Power the motor from an external supply instead of sourcing it from the Arduino.

Another thing that might help is to add some bypass capacitors as close as possible to the motor and to the temperature IC across the Vcc and GND lines.  This will help to smooth out the power in spite of the noise that the motor itself generates.  Generally you want at least one of two types, an electrolytic capacitor and a ceramic capacitor.  These are both inexpensive if you don't already have some on hand.  I'll suggest a 10 uF electrolytic and a 0.1 uF ceramic capacitor near both the motor and the temp sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the good advice from jwh20, you should start with a general strategy to find out where the problem lies.  You should hang a DVM directly between the sensor output and ground and see if the voltage also shows the rising problem.  If not, the trouble is in your code.

A drifting value is often due a wiring issue, like a bad sensor ground.  It wouldn't hurt to go over all the wiring very carefully.